How do I add another entry to grub?
I have 3 os's installed on my computer, Windows, EndeavourOS, and Kali. However, when I install Kali, only Windows and Kali show up in grub. How do I add Endeavouros?
os-prober returns: /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi (on kali).
The output of sudo update-grub is
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/kali/theme.txt
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.10.9-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.10.9-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.11-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.11-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done


(os-prober and update-grub don't help)
EDIT - lsblk returns
❯ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda            8:0    1  14.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1         8:1    1     4G  0 part 
└─sda2         8:2    1   6.3M  0 part 
nvme0n1      259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0   150M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2  259:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3  259:3    0 163.8G  0 part /winC
├─nvme0n1p4  259:4    0   1.3G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5  259:5    0 141.6G  0 part /winL
├─nvme0n1p6  259:6    0  63.5G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p7  259:7    0   4.9G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p8  259:8    0   990M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p9  259:9    0  16.2G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p10 259:10   0   1.4G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p11 259:11   0  44.4G  0 part /var/cache
│                                      /var/log
│                                      /home
│                                      /
├─nvme0n1p12 259:12   0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p13 259:13   0  26.6G  0 part 

nvme0n1p11 is endeavouros, p13 is kali, winC is my windows c drive, winL is my personal partition (for my documents).

What does your partition-table look like? Please edit your post and copy & paste the text output of lsblk into a code-block.

@tink i edited it in

All installs must be in same boot mode. Or all UEFI if Windows is UEFI which it probably is as p1 is an ESP - efi system partition. How to: Create a Customized GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.- Cavsfan
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen &
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config &
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus  And new pages: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205
